# Authentication for a webpage

Tags: authentication, html

I'm having a webpage on which I will try to make a nice authentication..

At the best I would like that only the users allowed should be able to visit it, without any password or stuff. Is that possible and how can I do that?

If it matters the application is written in c#

Otherwise anyone has any smooth tip?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts involved here:

1. Identifying the user and making sure it is what it tells to be (Authentication);
2. Allowing only some of the users to access your page (Authorization).

For your case, the second one should be easy, once you have done the first one. A good starting point would be [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)